# Joomla delete from page source Comments

Tags: joomla

I am trying to delete all mentioning of joomla from the page source of the following site:

http://signfit.multi-web-services.co.uk

In the page source its on around line 277 that i can't find where to delete the comments from, or If you inspect the element and then search it for joomla it returns with it present once.

This is the line that i am trying to delete:

```
<!-- JoomlaWorks "K2" (v2.6.4) | Learn more about K2 at http://getk2.org -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this on line **73** of

```
components/com_k2/k2.php
```

where you will see:

```
echo "\n<!-- JoomlaWorks \"K2\" (v2.6.8) | Learn more about K2 at http://getk2.org -->\n\n";
```

What I would recommend doing first is update to K2 2.6.8 as you are 4 versions behind, and **then** change this file as you wish. It's a core file so each time you update, you will have to perform this action every time.